# System Settings->Network grays and requires Force Quit

Tags: networking, network-manager, accessibility

I have a new NUC7i7BNH running Ubuntu as a dedicated Roon Core (server). I am a Linux newbie, but managed pretty well with the help of this site. (THANK YOU!)

However, everything was running fine until I shut down my *entire* system (network included) for a UPS swap, and then rebooted.

Now I can't open the Network panel in System Settings. Nor can I access the Internet in general. I had been able to do so previously, while getting things up and running.

All the other panels in System Settings seem to work normally. I have rebooted, but nothing changed. I am at a loss as to what happened. I am logged in as the Admin. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance. This community is great.